# Odd output of string in C

Tags: c, string

I received an assignment to write a code that would erase the instances of a string in another string, and although my code does that successfully, the symbol ╠ appears many times at the end of the result string.

Example:
For input string 1 - **A string is a string**, and an input string 2 - **str**
The result should be **A ing is a ing**.

But I receive **A ing is a ing╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠**

Hoped I could get some assistance regarding this issue, cause no matter what I've tried I wasn't able to
fix this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STRING_SIZE 100

int StrippingFunc(char input_str1[STRING_SIZE], char input_str2[STRING_SIZE], char 
result_string[STRING_SIZE])
{
  if (input_str2[0] == '\n' || input_str2[0] == '\0')
  {
    return 0;
  }
  for (int k1 = 0; k1 < STRING_SIZE; k1++)
  {
    if (input_str1[k1] == '\n')
    {
        input_str1[k1] = '\0';
    }
  }
  for (int k2 = 0; k2 < STRING_SIZE; k2++)
  {
    if (input_str2[k2] == '\n')
    {
        input_str2[k2] = '\0';
    }
  }

  int Length;
  int length2 = 0;
  int index2 = 0;
  while (input_str2[index2] != '\0') // Loop used to determine input_string2's length.
  {
    length2++;
    index2++;
  } 
  int InString = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int j;
  int resultindex = 0;

  while (input_str1[i] != '\0')
  {
    Length = length2;
    int l = i;
    j = 0;
    int proceed = 1;
    if (input_str1[l] == input_str2[j])
    {
        while ((input_str2[j] != '\0') && (proceed != 0))
        {
            while (Length >= 0)
            {
                if (Length == 0)
                {
                    InString = 1;
                    i += (l-i-1);
                    proceed = 0;
                    Length = -1;
                }
                if (input_str1[l] == input_str2[j])
                {
                    Length--;
                    j++;
                    l++;
                }
                else if ((input_str1[l-1] == input_str2[j-1]) && (input_str2[j] == '\0'))
                {
                    proceed = 0;
                    Length = -1;

                }
                else
                {
                    proceed = 0;
                    Length = -1;
                    result_string[resultindex] = input_str1[l - 1];
                    resultindex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result_string[resultindex] = input_str1[i];
        resultindex++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return InString;
}

int main()
{
  char result_string[STRING_SIZE];
  char input_string1[STRING_SIZE];
  char input_string2[STRING_SIZE];

  printf("Please enter the main string..\n");
  // Your function call here..
  fgets(input_string1, STRING_SIZE + 1, stdin);
  printf("Please enter the pattern string to find..\n");
  // Your function call here..
  fgets(input_string2, STRING_SIZE + 1, stdin);
  int is_stripped = StrippingFunc(input_string1, input_string2, result_string);; // Your function call here..
  // Store the result in the result_string if it exists

  printf("> ");
  printf(is_stripped ? result_string : "Cannot find the pattern in the string!");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not null-terminating the result string

Comment: `fgets(input_string1, STRING_SIZE + 1, stdin);` and `gets(input_string2, STRING_SIZE + 1, stdin);` may have undefined nehavior, why these +1 to allow to write out of the array ?

Comment: I tried null - terminating the result string but I'm not sure where should I insert that condition. I even tried making 2 result strings and entering that condition at the end of the code but there is no difference whatsoever...

Comment: They told us to obtain all the characters of the string including '\n', so I assumed I needed an additional slot

Comment: @RandyMarsh you have several problems in your code, not only one, read my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I receive A ing is a ing╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

In the code after you fill `result_string` but you missed to add the final null character, because of that the `printf` after reach non initialized characters with an undefined behavior producing your unexpected writting. After

> ```
>   while (input_str1[i] != '\0')
>   {
>      Length = length2;
>      ...
>   }
> ```

add

```
result_string[resultindex] = 0;
```

note you have the place for because `result_string` and `input_str1` have the same size

Having

> ```
> char input_string1[STRING_SIZE];
> char input_string2[STRING_SIZE];
> ```

these two lines can have an undefined behavior :

> ```
> fgets(input_string1, STRING_SIZE + 1, stdin);
> fgets(input_string2, STRING_SIZE + 1, stdin);
> ```

because `fgets` may write after the end of the arrays, you need to remove `+1` or to size the arrays one more

In

> ```
> for (int k1 = 0; k1 < STRING_SIZE; k1++)
> {
>    if (input_str1[k1] == '\n')
>    {
>      input_str1[k1] = '\0';
>    }
>  }
>  for (int k2 = 0; k2 < STRING_SIZE; k2++)
>  {
>    if (input_str2[k2] == '\n')
>    {
>      input_str2[k2] = '\0';
>    }
>  }
> ```

except if `fgets` fill all the arrays you have an undefined behavior working on non initialized characters because you do not stop when you reach newline or the null character.

In

> ```
> int length2 = 0;
> int index2 = 0;
> while (input_str2[index2] != '\0') // Loop used to determine input_string2's length.
> {
>   length2++;
>   index2++;
> }
> ```

*length2* and *length2* have exactly the same value, is it useless to have two variables, and in fact this lop is useless because the previous loop with the right termination already give you the expected length.

In

> ```
>   printf(is_stripped ? result_string : "Cannot find the pattern in the string!");
> ```

I encourage you to replace `printf` by a `puts` not only to add a final newline to flush the output and make it more clear in case you start your program in a shell, but also because in case the input string contains for instance `%d` and it is not removed and `is_stripped` is true then `printf` will try to  get an argument whose do not exist, with an undefined behavior

If you do all the corrections with your inputs your code will print `> A ing is a ing` without undefined behavior

Comment: Yo, you're the man. This worked immediately. Thank you for your help, you saved me a lot of precious time!